# How does "prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGKILL)" do

Tags: c, process, signals, child-process, sigkill

Hi i was reading a C code that creates a child process via `clone()`, and in the child process/function there is a line that i don't clearly understand :

```
prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGKILL)
```

i searched for a while about `prctl()` and about this particular line, and what i understood is that it will kill the child process if the parent thread dies.

i know that if the parent thread exits/dies a `PR_SET_PDEATHSIG` signal will be sent to the child (if my 1st guess is true), and i know what `SIGKILL` means, but i don't understand what `pctrl()` does with them both, does it mean :

- if the parent thread dies then the child process receives a `PR_SET_PDEATHSIG` signal then he will send a `SIGKILL` to itself. OR :
- `PR_SET_PDEATHSIG` is not even a signal and it is used to refer to the parent thread death, and what the line means is if the parent thread exits/dies then the child process will receive `SIGKILL` signal. OR:
- something else, kindly clarify

The C code is something like this:

```
#INCLUDES

static int child_function( ... ) {

   if( prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGKILL) )
       printf("ERROR");

   //CHILD CODE
}

int main( ... ) {
  //PARENT CODE

  int child_pid = clone(child_function, ...);

  //PARENT CODE
}
```

Comment: If the parent process exits, the kernel will send SIGKILL to the child process.

Comment: @Shawn thank you, kindly write it in as an answer so i can accept it :)